# SQLalchemy Avoid duplicate in session() before commiting

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

While trying to commit rows with SQLalchemy using session.merge(), I get an error of duplicates.

I think it is because the databse where I fetch the data allows duplicates of columns "hash" and the new one doesn't.

Is there a simple way to avoid or remove duplicates in the current session before committing ?

Here is an example:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
    from src.python.utils import _gen_relationship

    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pssw}@{host}/{db}?charset=utf8'.
                               format(user=config['user'],
                                      pssw=config['password'],
                                      host=config['host'],
                                      db=config['database'])
                               )

    database = [
        {'c_hash': 'd182jd012jd102jd1', 'date': '2017-01-01', 'text': 'oijwdqoijwdqoiqwdm'},
        {'c_hash': 'apiowjdaowndoaiwjda', 'date': '2017-01-01', 'text': 'oijwdqoijwdqoiqwdm'},
        {'c_hash': 'd182jd012jd102jd1', 'date': '2017-01-02', 'text': 'adawdawdawd'}
    ]

    Base = automap_base()
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, generate_relationship=_gen_relationship)

    # load necessary table information
    Mytable = Base.classes.mytable

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
    session = Session()

    for row in database:
        new_row = {
            'hash': row['c_hash'],
            'date': row['date'],
            'text': row['text']
        }

        session.merge(Mytable(**new_row))
    session.commit()
```

Thank you

Comment: Your DB is avoiding duplicates as is, but I guess you mean that you'd like to eliminate duplicates from your input based on some criteria. That's not the session's job, but your application's. You could for example wrap each merge in a savepoint and flush, ignoring integrity errors caused by dupes, or just remove dupes before even passing the data to the session.

Comment: Is there a way to query the lines that have been added to the current session ? The workaround that I found is to commit at every line but this is very slow...

Comment: Btw. where're `c_hash` and `text` coming from? Please provide a [mcve]. Include a small sample of input data and expected result.

Comment: here you go. As you can see, there is a duplicate in the commit. Is there a way to easily deal with this?

Comment: The `text` and `date` value seem to be different between the 2. Which one should be discarded?

Comment: The best would be to keep the last row added to the session, but it doesn't matter too much for now !!

Comment: Just one more question. Are you using `Session.merge()` on purpose? As in, you know your DB might contain entities with the same primary key already and you want to update those based on the data from your input.

Comment: Yes exactly it is on purpose considering that hash is the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd seem that you might be better off "deduplicating" in your application:

```
seen = set()

# Reversed so that the last row wins.
for row in reversed(database):
    c_hash = row['c_hash']
    if c_hash not in seen:
        session.merge(Mytable(hash=c_hash,
                              date=row['date'],
                              text=row['text']))
        seen.add(c_hash)
```

In theory you could let SQLAlchemy handle the deduplication as well:

```
for row in database:
    session.merge(Mytable(hash=row['c_hash'],
                          date=row['date'],
                          text=row['text']))
    session.flush()
```

The trick is to flush in between, so that later merges will consult the DB and find the existing row, but this will be performing more queries, compared to the other solution.